# Как переделать класс в синглтон?

Tags: java, hibernate

Нужно Клас Util - сделать синглтон(lazy). Решаю задачу, сказали переделать под синглтон, вообще не получается разобраться и как это реализовать, могли бы помочь?

Класс Util

```
public class Util {

private static Util util;
private static String logFile = "this is log file \n\n";

public static synchronized Util getUtil() {
    if (util == null) {
       util = new Util();
    }
    return util;
}

private Util() {

}

public void addLogInfo(String logInfo) {
    logFile += logInfo + "\n";
}

public void showLogFile() {
    System.out.println(logFile);
}

// реализуйте настройку соеденения с БД
private static String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user";
private static String dbUsername = "root";
private static String dbPassword = "root";
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static Connection connection =null;




public static Connection getConnection() {

    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUsername, dbPassword);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.setProperty("connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", dbURL)
                    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username",dbUsername)
                    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", dbPassword)
                    .setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect")
                    .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true")
                    .addAnnotatedClass(jm.task.core.jdbc.model.User.class);
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception" + e);
        }
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            getConnection().close();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (sessionFactory != null) {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
}
```

Класс Main

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Util.getUtil().addLogInfo("Singleton");
    Util.getUtil().showLogFile();

    // реализуйте алгоритм здесь
    User[] users ={new User("Daniil", "Vaskin", (byte) 99),
            new User("Kolya","Ivanov",(byte) 15),
            new User("Ivan","Ivanov", (byte) 16),
            new User("Maksim","Gantelya",(byte) 24)};
    UserService userServ = new UserServiceImpl();
    userServ.createUsersTable();
    for (User user : users) {
        userServ.saveUser(user.getName(), user.getLastName(), user.getAge());
        System.out.printf("Челика добавили в базу \n", user.getName());
    }
    userServ.cleanUsersTable();
    userServ.dropUsersTable();

    Util.shutdown();
}
}
```

Comment: помочь могли бы, если бы код не был выложен на стороннем ресурсе. Локализуйте проблему и приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример

Comment: @ArchDemon исправил, попробовал прописать, но не уверен, что правильно

Comment: Если глобально вам помочь, то используйте фреймворк spring. Если вы в образовательных целях занимаетесь, то синглтон является анти-шаблоном проектирования. Лучше, конечно, заменять его не шаблон Service Locator, который тоже анти-шаблон проектирования, но всё же лучше. Если вы всё же не передумали, то в классе Util статической переменной должна быть только `util` (обычно её называют `INSTANCE`), а метод её получения обычно называют `getInstance()` (у вас `getUtil()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае синхронизация метода `getUtil` представляется излишней, так как при каждом обращении к экземпляру синглтона блокируется данный класс, и для решения этой проблемы существует известный подход с двойной проверкой:

```java
public class Util {
    private static volatile Util INSTANCE;

    public static Util getInstance() {
        if (null == INSTANCE) {
            synchronized(Util.class) {
                if (null == INSTANCE) {
                    INSTANCE = new Util();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    // private конструктор и др. методы
}
```

Следует также заметить, что статические методы для работы с соединением к базе данных не требуют создания синглтона.

Другой известный подход - с "ленивой" инициализацией по требованию при помощи вложенного статического класса, так как известно, что инициализация класса происходит при первом обращении к полю/методу такого класса, а также, что статическая инициализация потокобезопасна ([JLS 12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)):

> *For each class or interface `C`, there is a unique initialization lock `LC`.*

```java
public class Util {
    private static class UtilInstance {
        private static final Util INSTANCE = new Util();
    }

    public static Util getInstance() {
        return UtilInstance.INSTANCE;
    }

    // private конструктор и др. методы
}
```

---

Однако, наиболее простое идиоматическое решение из книги "Effective Java" -- использовать `enum` вместо класса:

```java
public enum Util {
    INSTANCE;
}

Util.INSTANCE.foo();
```

JVM гарантированно создаст экземпляр `Util` при первом обращении к полю `enum`

Comment: большое спасибо за доходчивый ответ!!